# How do I use the WorldInfo gpsReference? It doesn't work as expected

Tags: ros, gps, webots

I'm experiencing some challenges trying to get a realistic GPS output from my simulation. I'm based in New Zealand so my real-world Lat/Long is in the -40.3789 and 175.6129 range in WGS84, but when I set the WorldInfo of my simulation to these values, the position response from my GPS devices is way off from that reference.

I've manually dropped the x value of the offset to minimise variables, and it is as expected in most of the positive range as so:
[image: Webots screenshot of gpsReference]

But if the x value of the reference drops below 0, the output latitude of the gps device drops instantly to -109, and longitude jumps to 181 instead of the 175 it should never have changed from.

[image: Result of negative latitude]

The resulting gps lat long should be around the same -40, 175 right? Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I misunderstanding something about how this system works?

Thanks in advance